# Varnish ignoring settings and not showing hits or misses

Tags: amazon-ec2, varnish, varnish-vcl

I've spun up a new Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance and installed varnish on top of it via the following process:

1. Installed varnish with `sudo yum install varnish` and set it to run on startup
2. Setup `/etc/sysconfig/varnish` to point varnish to listen to port 80
3. Added a off the shelf WordPress `/etc/varnish/defualt.vcl` from [this repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lawrencemcdaniel-dot-com/varnish/master/default.vcl)
4. Modified `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to have apache look at port 8080
5. Restarted httpd and varnish

When running `/usr/sbin/varnishd -V` I get the following: varnishd (varnish-3.0.7 revision f544cd8)

And it works. Kind of. It seems to be having the following issues:

When up and running, if I hit a page it will load fully, then serve the varnish cached page as expected, headers all setup correctly. However the cache will die after 120 seconds, not the time set in the `default.vcl` file. However if I make a deliberate error in the default.vcl file, varnish will not start.

When using `varnishstat`, `varnishtop` or `varnishsizes` nothing shows up. I get the default screen for each process but no hits or misses or sizes show up at all.

Varnish does not seem to want to run properly on startup and after being left ticking over with no access to the server for a week varnish seems to have stopped working. Along with this when running `service varnish restart` Stopping the cache always fails.

**/etc/sysconfig/varnish** https://pastebin.com/UmamLFMG

**/etc/varnish/default/vcl** https://pastebin.com/C3JdkuUe

**/etc/https/conf/httpd.conf** https://pastebin.com/TzvDVhkq

Comment: try this command `sudo varnishstat`

Comment: Varnish 3 is way too old and unsupported. You may want to install Varnish 4 or 6 LTS either from [official](https://varnish-cache.org/releases/install_redhat.html#install-redhat) or [GetPageSpeed](https://www.getpagespeed.com/redhat) repositories.

Comment: @hoseinz3 I've been running in sudo when trying these.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin I'm confused as to how the .main install only gives version 3 is we're up to 6, but I guess I have some googling to do, thanks.

Comment: The base RedHat (and derivative OS-es alike) are well known to have older versions with back-ported security fixes. Well, sometimes *way too old* versions :)

Comment: @DanilaVershinin I just looked up the versioning and that is very confusing numbering systems they seem to have going on there. no wonder the default yum installer is just sat at v3

Comment: What headers are you getting? Are you sure the browser is not asking for a newer version? Just because it's storing the response for 7 days doesn't mean that's what it's going to serve. Also, cookies.

Comment: By "die" do you mean the varnish process crashes/is unresponsive? What size EC2 instance (as you have asked for a 1GB in memory cache)? Your varnish daemon flags also set a default TTL of 120 seconds, this might be related.